# Set filename character encoding in Putty's PSFTP

Tags: encoding, putty, psftp

I am using PuTTY's command line utility **psftp.exe** to transfer files between a UTF8-configured linux server and a MS Windows PC.

File names containing non ASCII characters (e.g., Japanese kana) are corrupted when using the 'ls' or 'get' commands of the psftp utility.

I tried to create a saved session from putty.exe with the translation set to UTF8, and use that saved session from psftp.exe (i.e., open saved_session_with_UTF8_translation), but the filename characters were still corrupted.

How can I configure psftp.exe so that it uses the right charset for the file names?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using tar(1) to make an archive of the files before you send them. Most (Windows) programs that support GNU Tarballs support converting the filenames to the Windows character set.

Comment: Can you give an example of a Windows program that would do such a conversion?  I tried 7-Zip to uncompress a tar file, but it does not convert the file names and so creates corrupted file names, just like psftp.exe.